# Python requests NOT Throwing an Exception When Using Session with HTTPAdapter

Tags: python, python-requests

I monitor several of the dynamic DNS entries created on my service using python, but for some reason, one host `macmillan.dynamix.pro` is causing the script to freeze indefinitely.

The below code uses the requests head method to get a status code.  The first try catch block doesn't use a Retry() object, and an exception is thrown as expected.  However, the second try catch block doesn't throw an exception, and the script freezes indefinitely from using the requests.Session() object created from `def requests_retry_session`

```
############################
#  Imports                 #
############################

from urlparse import urlparse
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
import httplib
import re
import urllib2
import socket
import requests # sudo pip install requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

# Below comes from https://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-practice-with-retries-with-requests
def requests_retry_session(
        retries=0,
        backoff_factor=1,
        status_forcelist=(500, 502, 504),
        session=None,
):
        session = session or requests.Session()
        retry = Retry(
                total=None,
                read=retries,
                connect=retries,
                backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
                status=retries,
                status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
        )
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        session.mount('http://', adapter)
        session.mount('https://', adapter)
        return session

try:
        urlResp = requests.head("https://macmillan.dynamix.pro", timeout=(3, 3), verify=False)
        status = str(urlResp.status_code)
        print "Status is " + status
except Exception as e:
        print "bad " + str(e)

try:
        urlResp = requests_retry_session().head("https://macmillan.dynamix.pro", timeout=(3, 3), verify=False)
        status = str(urlResp.status_code)
        print "Status is " + status
except Exception as e:
        print "bad " + str(e)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: If you set the total property in the Retry object to `False`, an exception is thrown, and the script no longer runs indefinitely.  So why does it not terminate unless `total` is set to `False`?

Comment: Have you tried total=3? Or 10, the default? I ran your code, and both exceptions were caught.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay the docs state that if you use total=None it is supposed to ignore it and go with the connect and read retry count which in my case is 0, so why doesn't `None` work?

Comment: It should work. What version of Python and Requests are you using? These two setups worked for me: `Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` with `requests 2.19.1`, and `Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` with `requests 2.20.0`. (I replaced your `print` statements with calls to `print()`)

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.12 for it.  Requests Version: 2.21.0 - seems to fail in latest version of Python 2.7.x as well.